# Java , Jboss, How to load a property file which is in jboss class path

Tags: java, properties, configuration, jboss

I have a properties file inside `JBOSS_HOME/server/all/conf` folder say `app.properties`. How can I access that file from inside my `App.war` file.

I kept it there for easy configuration of application without any rebuilding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be you can look for JBOSS_HOME from system properties), assuming you have environment variable setup.

Comment: Is there any other method so as to avoid configuring path of properties file?

Answer (score 1):

jboss.server.config.url system property provides the URL for the server/all/conf directory

```
String path = System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.url" + your_file_name.properties);
```